# ¿ Cómo comparar fechar en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Cómo comparo dos fechas correctamente estoy comparando dos fechas si la fecha actual es mayor a la que se ingresa debe salir una `alerta` y si no lo es debe mostrar un `div`,no me muestra la alerta y si mi abre el `div` así sea mayor o no me abre el `div`,entonces pienso que no me esta reconociendo la comparación en mi `if`

**código**

```
function fnpasarf2(){

        var fechafin =  document.getElementById("fechafin").value;
        var fecha_actual = new Date();

        if(fecha_fin > fecha_actual)
        {
          alert("MENSAJE : EL PACIENTE NO TERMINA SU TRATAMIENTO DE PRIMERA FASE");
        }else{
          console.log(fechafin,fecha_actual);
          $("#formulario_esquema2").fadeIn("slow");
        }


    }
```

**html**

```
<input type='date' id='fechafin' name='fechafin' value='$fechafinf1' Readonly>
<input type='button' id='pasarf2' class='pasarf2' name='pasarf2' value='PASAR FASE2' onclick="fnpasarf2()">
```

Comment: Da un vistazo a -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: fechafin es un string. tienes que convirtirlo a Date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo primero que necesitas saber respecto a las fechas es que para pasar un String a Date solo tienes que crear un objeto tipo Date pasándole como argumento el String de la fecha. Cuando tengas el objeto Date ya puedes obtener el tiempo con el método getTime del objeto Date, y compararlo con el getTime de otro objeto Date como en el siguiente ejemplo:

**UNA OBSERVACION EN TU VAR fecha_fin primero lo llamas fechafin.**

```
if( (new Date(fecha_fin).getTime() > new Date(fecha_actual).getTime()))
    {
       alert("MENSAJE : EL PACIENTE NO TERMINA SU TRATAMIENTO DE PRIMERA FASE");
    }else{
      console.log(fecha_fin,fecha_actual);
      $("#formulario_esquema2").fadeIn("slow");
        }
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo,si funciono

Comment: @popisw No olvides de marcarla como correcta, para que la pregunta sea cerrada